# How to access router from nuxtjs store?

Tags: vuex, vue-router, nuxtjs

I tried this but only got an error message

This relative module was not found:
* ./router in ./store/index.js

```js
// Ran with yarn dev
import router from './router'

export const state = () => ({
  authenticated: false,
})

export const mutations = {
  toggleLogin(state, loginStatus, path) {
    state.authenticated = loginStatus
    if (loginStatus) {
      router.push(path)
    } else {
      router.push('login')
    }
  },
}
```

My store path is store/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Vuex mutations and getters doesn't have access to the Vue context. Only actions does.

Also, you can't import the Nuxt router like that. What's that file you're trying to import?

I'd suggest to make an action instead:

```js
export const actions: {
  toggleLogin({ commit }, payload) {
    this.app.router.push('') //exists
  }
}
```